# C# MVC - Passing URL parameters to methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having trouble passing url paramaters to my method in my MVC project.
Currently experiencing the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SinglePost(Int32)' in 'mybloggywog.Controllers.PostController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Call is below:

```
@{

    foreach (var article in ViewBag.DisplayPosts)
    {
        <a class="ArticleLink" href="@Url.Action("SinglePost", "Post", article.Id)">@article.Title</a>
        <p>@article.CreatedOn</p>
        <br/>
    }       
}
```

Routeconfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Post",
            "post/{id}",
            new { controller = "Post", action = "SinglePost", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And method:

```
public ActionResult SinglePost(int id)
    {
        var entities = new blogEntities();

        var post = entities.Set<Post>();

        var postToDisplay = (from p in post
                             where p.Id == id
                             select p);

        ViewBag.SinglePost = postToDisplay;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to an anonymous object:

```
@Url.Action("SinglePost", "Post", new { id = article.Id })
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I cannot upvote as yet, but I salute you, sir.